# Double colons before class names in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seen a lot usage of double colons in Rails before class names.

For example:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
```

I know what `Module::Class::Constant` means, but `::Class` ?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It means that you're referring to the constant `File` from the toplevel namespace. This makes sense in situations like this:

```
class MyClass #1
end

module MyNameSpace
  class MyClass #2
  end

  def foo # Creates an instance of MyClass #1
    ::MyClass.new # If I left out the ::, it would refer to
                  # MyNameSpace::MyClass instead.
  end
end
```

Comment: Can we say that it behaves like `cd ..` (go up one level while resolving namespace ?)

Comment: More like `cd /` where you go to the root level (global namespace)