# uninitilize class after change route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Hei guys i working on rest api on ruby on rails i tried to make simple my route using group it by what module is

so i go like this

```
namespace :backend do
namespace :merchant do
  resources :merchants
end
resources :owners
```

and my controller was like this

```
class Backend::Merchant::MerchantsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # http://localhost:3000/backend/merchants
    # on post request get all merchant
    allMerchant = Merchant.all
    render json: allMerchant
 end
end
```

and i got error like

> uninitialized constant Backend::Merchant::MerchantsController::Merchant

it because my model class not regonize by controller on this part

> allMerchant = Merchant.all

my code struktur is like

```
controller
   |
   ---- backend
           |
           ---- merchant
                   |
                   ---- merchant_controller.rb


model
  |
   ---- merchant.rb
```

i realy appreciate any suppor for you all

NB i using mongoid

Comment: have you tried `allMerchant = ::Merchant.all`

Comment: @gaotongfei it work dude thank a lot but can you explain what i happen

Comment: this explains https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819370/7313509, it basically  means that you are referring `Merchant` from the top-level namespace, instead of `Backend::Merchant::MerchantsController`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add merchant in the backend it's an indentation issue just change it to like this:

`namespace :backend do
  namespace :merchant do
    resources :merchants
  end
resources :owners`

Comment: i use allMerchant = ::Merchant.all

Comment: Okay good i was facing same error and i fixed it for me it was indentation issue